# How to match the ip address with maximind data?

Tags: node.js, csv, redis, ip-address

I am working on analytics, For finding the location of the user i am using maximind data.

Currently i am using [kuno](https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP) to fetch the location information using ip address.

For Example:

**Input** is ip address(1.0.0.0)

**output** is location(Australia)

### Problem

kuno uses `.dat` or `.csv` file to fetch location using ip. My app should suppose to handle 1000 req/sec. Each request should fetch the location information, so opening the `.dat` or `.csv` file 1000 times throwing error and some lack in performance.

So i decided to port the data(csv) file to [redis](http://redis.io/) database.

#### Below are the format of CSV file:

```
Start ip,   End ip,   Location

"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","Japan"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","China"
```

Two things i got confused

1. How to find the range of given ip address by match with start and end ip address?
2. Using `redis db` for this purpose is good approach?

Any help or suggestion is great.

I am ready to explain more if it is confusing

Comment: how were you doing (1) before using redis?

Comment: I thought of adding ip address as key and location as value in redis db. I port the csv to redis once i get the idea of 1. At the same time   i am new to redis so i am asking suggestion. Redis is based on key value pair so it is easy to port data to it.

Comment: I am asking how were you matching the ip ranges before you decided to use redis?

Comment: Right now i am using https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP module in node.js to get the location. Example :https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP/blob/master/USAGE.md

Comment: You mean Find the country location by given ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Redis for this is a great idea.

Assuming you are handling IPV4 addresses only, you could use the three first parts of the IP address. It doesn't look like the last part is significant when looking for the country.

I think you could store all of the data in a unique redis sorted set. The values will be the name of countries. And the score the end IP address, converted to decimal.

By example:

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","Australia"
 1.0.0 ==> score = 1x256x256 + 0 x 256 + 0, gives you a score of 65536 for Australia
```

Register this in a Redis Sorted Set named 'countries':

```
ZADD countries 65536 "Australia@65536"
```

Nb: I concatenate the score with the country name just to ensure the stored value is unique. It will allow to register more than one IP range for each country.

```
1.0.1 ==> score = 1x256x256 + 0 x 256 + 1, i.e. score = 65537 for China

ZADD countries 65537 "China@65537"
```

1.0.7 ==> score = 65543 for Australia

1.0.15 ==> score = 65551 for China

And so on...

When you want to check a given IP address, apply the same algorithm. By example if you want to find the country for 1.0.5.23, you compute a score of

```
1x65536 + 0x256 + 5 = 65541
```

Now you make a request to Redis:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE countries 65541 +inf LIMIT 0 1
```

It will return you the first value, with a score at least equal to 65541. It's the name of the country (of course you'll have to drop the last part of the returned string).

The performance of the search will depend on the number of items in the sorted set. 
If N is this number, the time complexity of the search will be O(Log(N)).

I have no idea of the number of items in your set (that it to say the number of IP ranges), but if you have any performance problem, you can split data in multiple sorted sets.

Use the first part of the IP address as a part of the sorted set key (countries:1 stores the data for IP address from 1.0.0.0 to 1.255.255.255, countries:2 stores the data for IP address from 2.0.0.0 to 2.255.255.255, etc).

Then use the same principle as above but with a score computed from the second and third parts of the end IP address, and look in the sorted set corresponding to the first part.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got one issue, I added all the converted numbers of end ip in redis sorted set. it is showing wrong location while searching using the ip address.  For clarification: Only end ip(converted value using above algorithm) values is to be stored in sorted set right?

Comment: That's the idea yes. I just made a quick test when writing my answer and it returned the correct country, so I assumed my answer was correct, but my data set was small (4 IP ranges, 2 countries) and I only made 1 test. Not enough to ensure everything was OK. When you say it's returning the wrong country, is it something like he following one or the previous one in ip ranges?

Comment: For Example: I added all the end ip like ZADD country 65536 "Australia"
ZADD country 65539 "China",
ZADD country 65543 "Australia",
ZADD country 65551 "China",
ZADD country 65567 "Japan",
ZADD country 65599 "China"   when i try to fetch the location for 1.0.2.255 uisng the query ZRANGEBYSCORE country 65538 +inf LIMIT 0 1. It is giving Australia but it is china.

Comment: The error was rather obvious. You can't store more than once a value in a sorted set, 'cause it's... a set. I updated my answer to reflect that.